# Why would a branch created off of another branch be different than the parent branch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

So I have a branch `develop`, and I created a new branch off of it `git checkout -b syntax_highlight`.

The issue is, when I go to my new branch, my `Gemfile` is different in the new branch than the parent branch.

As in, I have the `Gemfile` opened in the background, and I can see it change when I switch branches.

Yet there is nothing staged.

```
$ git checkout syntax_highlight
Already on 'syntax_highlight'
$ git rebase develop
Current branch syntax_highlight is up to date.
$ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
$ git checkout syntax_highlight
Switched to branch 'syntax_highlight'
$ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
$ git status
# On branch develop
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ git checkout syntax_highlight
Switched to branch 'syntax_highlight'
$ git status
# On branch syntax_highlight
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why there are differences in my `Gemfile` and it makes me wonder if there are other differences that git is not telling me about.

**Edit 1**

After running `git log` on both branches, you will see that both have the same commits, except that the `syntax_highlight` branch has 1 more recent commit - which makes sense, because that is that is the branch I am currently working on.

```
$ git log
commit a0b320a001cb24f42e2cf0f3dfee38cfd53e2290
Author: marcamillion
Date:   Thu Mar 28 02:27:08 2013 -0500

    Got the HABTM counter_cache working.

commit 64b73338c34259f02daa2ed943bd5d47ac5bacc0
Author: marcamillion
Date:   Mon Mar 25 03:16:43 2013 -0500

    Added the basic sidebar layout.

commit 7989813e9a379e480500f12ee01367967b791cd4
Author: marcamillion
Date:   Sun Mar 24 14:36:33 2013 -0500

    Got the basics of the sidebar layout, along with the navigational bar listing useful tags.

commit 1f0feea2f6db36e5c89aaf83c51cfc3b4bdbf01f
Author: marcamillion
Date:   Sun Mar 24 02:48:20 2013 -0500

    Installed bullet gem.


##

$ git checkout syntax_highlight
Switched to branch 'syntax_highlight'
$ git log
commit cccc5cd3350dbcd751e1ceccd0d4865948fd6993
Author: marcamillion
Date:   Thu Mar 28 03:02:20 2013 -0500

    Installed pygments, but haven't been able to test successfully yet.

commit a0b320a001cb24f42e2cf0f3dfee38cfd53e2290
Author: marcamillion
Date:   Thu Mar 28 02:27:08 2013 -0500

    Got the HABTM counter_cache working.

commit 64b73338c34259f02daa2ed943bd5d47ac5bacc0
Author: marcamillion
Date:   Mon Mar 25 03:16:43 2013 -0500

    Added the basic sidebar layout.

commit 7989813e9a379e480500f12ee01367967b791cd4
Author: marcamillion
Date:   Sun Mar 24 14:36:33 2013 -0500

    Got the basics of the sidebar layout, along with the navigational bar listing useful tags.

commit 1f0feea2f6db36e5c89aaf83c51cfc3b4bdbf01f
Author: marcamillion
Date:   Sun Mar 24 02:48:20 2013 -0500

    Installed bullet gem.
```

**Edit 2**

This is the result of a `git diff` of a specific :

```
$ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r cccc5cd3350dbcd751e1ceccd0d4865948fd6993
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
app/assets/stylesheets/pygments.css.erb
app/views/home/index.html.erb
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why do you expect it to be the same (unless you are sure you have never committed the file). Can you run git log on both branches?

Comment: The same commit I see on my `develop` branch, is the same commit I am seeing on my `syntax_highlight` branch.

Comment: I added the output to the question.

Comment: Any chance you have your Gemfile in .gitignore? Check `git status --ignored`

Comment: Nope....nothing. `$ git status --ignored
# On branch syntax_highlight
nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

Comment: Here is the weird thing about this....the `Gemfile` is not showing the missing gem, but my app is throwing an error because the views have the calls associated with that missing gem. So it seems that the views are right, it's just the `Gemfile` and I assume `Gemfile.lock` that are wrong.

Comment: I don't know much about ruby, so can't help here, but it seems to be a git issue rather than ruby.  Any chance you actually committed it with the last commit? `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r cccc5cd3350dbcd751e1ceccd0d4865948fd6993`

Comment: Updated the question with the results of that `git diff`

Answer (score 0):

Your commit from cccc5cd3350dbcd751e1ceccd0d4865948fd6993 has updated the Gemfile... so expect to see your Gemfile update... When you rebase off of develop, your just reapplying your commit on top of any changes to develop ( none ).  The only change on your syntax_highlight branch is said commit above that updated the Gemfile.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Not really. Can you phrase it another way? Ok I re-read it, and I kinda get what you are saying. But that's the thing, so my `Gemfile` has `gem A` in it - in branch `develop`. I created the `syntax_highlight` gem off of that branch - so shouldn't the Gemfile in the new branch contain `gem A` given that I am taking all the commits from `develop` and building on top of that?

Comment: Considering there was a change made to the Gemfile on the new branch, the best possible explanation is that it was removed on the new branch.  Here is an exercise that should answer the question:  Jump back to develop.  Create another branch `test_funky_behavior_2` or something.  Make a commit that has nothing to do with the Gemfile.  Now, the Gemfile should be the same.  Go ahead and rebase off develop ( which should do nothing ).  You should still see no change.  If we see this behavior, only explanation is that syntax_highlight removed Gam A.  Can you git diff that Gemfile comparing branch?